# Why List[T] and not List[Int]? What does T mean?

Tags: scala

In all the examples I am ready this kind of function definition keeps popping up:

```
def firstElementInList[T](l: List[T]): T
```

I'm used to seeing `List[Int]` so it would be a list of integers. In this case I'm assuming that `T` is any type (please correct me if im wrong). What I'm really getting caught up on is the `[T]` right after `firstElementInList`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IT is just a way to tell: *this function references one generic type `T`* (you are right `T` is *any type*).

If you have multiple methods inside one class:

```
def firstElementInList[T](l: List[T]): T = l.head
def  lastElementInList[T](l: List[T]): T = l.last
```

then each method has its own `T` type, so you can call first method with a list of `String`s and a second one with a list of `Int`s.

However the whole class enclosing both of these methods can have type as well:

```
class Foo[T] {
  def firstElementInList(l: List[T]): T = l.head
  def  lastElementInList(l: List[T]): T = l.last
}
```

In this case you pick type during `Foo` object creation:

```
val foo = new Foo[String]
```

and the compiler will prevent you from calling instance methods of `foo` with any other type than `List[String]`. Also note that in this case you no longer need type `[T]` for a method - it is taken from the enclosing class.

Comment: Ahh.. so if you do `new Foo[String]` all of the `T`'s will be of type `String`?

Comment: @locrizak. Yes. Not only the compiler will not let you to call `new Foo[String].firstElementInList(List(1,2,3)`, but also `Foo[String]` and `Foo[Int]` are considered to be completely different types.

Answer (score 3):

T is an "unbound" type.  In other words, `List<T>` is shorthand for "list of things".

This means you can use the same code to make a "list of people" a "list of dates" or a "list of accounts", you just provide the constructor

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
```

Which will bind `T` to People.  Now when you access the `List` it will guarantee that everywhere the previously unbound `T` existed, it will act as if it was written with "People" in that position.  For example, `public T remove(int)` will return a `T` which is bound to "People" in the people list.  This avoids the need to add explicit casts.  It also guarantees that the only items within the `List` are *at least* People.

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();  // T is bound to "People"
List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();   // T is bound to "Account"
Person first = people.remove(0);
Account firstAccount = accounts.remove(0);

// The following line fails because Java doesn't automatically cast (amongst classes)
Account other = people.remove(0);

// as people is a List<T> where T is bound to "People", people.remove(0) will return
// a T which is bound to People.  In short it will return something that is at least an
// instance of People.  This doesn't cast into an account (even though there are other
// lists which would).
```

Note that the *at least* People comment is an indicator that the list might contain multiple objects, but all the objects must be sub-classes of People.

Answer (score 1):

That is *parameterisation* of function: your guess was correct: if you pass `List` of `Ints` to it, that function should return `Int`, if you pass `List` of `Strings`, return value should be `String`, and so on.
Moreover, you able to use this type in functions scope, e.g. like this:

```
def foo[T](l: List[T]): T = {
...
val z = collections.mutable.HashMap[String,T]
...
}
```